# How to build a trapeze menu background with 50% width

Tags: html, css

How can I build a trapeze shape background for a website menu? The height should be always 100% of the screen.

I have a code for rectangle shape, but I don't know how to add a triangle that has always the same angle?

Here some my code:

https://codepen.io/mattkr/pen/jOPxLQJ

The shape should look like this:

https://prnt.sc/rh2c62

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `linear-gradient(71deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FF3C23 50%)`

---

```css
div {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: linear-gradient(71deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FF3C23 50%)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style:

```
.header__nav::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  left: -30px;
  transform: skewX(5deg);
}
```

You can adjust the angle by increasing the skew angle, but you also have to increase the `width` and decrease the `left` value in the same ratio.

For example, if you increase skew angle to 10 then you have to increase `width` to `120px` and decrease the `left` value to `-60px`.